# Troubles with Drupal IMCE image upload

Tags: drupal, upload

I got some problems with Drupal's IMCE module. When I try to upload inline images from admin, it doesn't upload any images. I get this JS error on firebug:

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.mydomain.com/imce?jsop=upload&dir=."

If I go to that URL it gives me 404 not found page. If I go on my other Drupal that uses same system, it gives me JSON data result with same URL. Settings are same. And it has worked before on both systems. Now just it stopped on another one.

Also all the files folder should have correct rights. Is it some JS thing or? Anyone have had anything similar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I was having this issue too. For me it was a conflict with the Fast 404 module I had installed also. If you've got that module installed try disabling it to see if it fixes the problem. If it does then you'll want to look into using an advanced config for fast 404. Details of that are outlined in the readme.txt file in the fast_404 module dir.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem too.
instead of disabling the module, I whitelisted the string `jsop` in `sites/default/settings.php`

```
$conf['fast_404_string_whitelisting'][] = 'jsop';
```

That fixed the problem.

Important: If you are editing `sites/default/settings.php`, first give write permission to that file first. edit it, and dont forget to set permission to `444` after editing.
[Here is why](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/16994)

Answer (score 0):

I fix my problem with this missing line in settings.php:

```
$conf['404_fast_paths_exclude'] = '/\/(?:styles|advagg_(cs|j)s)|(?:system\/files)\//';
```